# *** glibc detected *** realloc(): invalid old size 3

Tags: c, memory-management

This code sometimes give me a Segmentation fault, why could this be?

```
void concatenarAlBuffer(char **destino, char caracter)
{
char matrizAux[1];
matrizAux[0]=caracter;
matrizAux[1]='\0';

(*destino) = realloc((*destino),2+(strlen((*destino))*sizeof(char)));

if ((*destino)==NULL)   
{                               
    perror("Error al reservar memoria\n");
    exit(-1);                               
}

strcat((*destino),matrizAux);
}
```

Comment: By the way, there is no need to use a temporary buffer on the stack just to add the NUL char; you could simply do `strncat(*destino, &caracter, 1);` after possibly growing `*destino` with `realloc()`. And also, I personally would not use `strcat()` having called `strlen()` before, because I feel that wastes CPU, but one might argue that the code is more readable doing so.

Comment: How do you use `concatenarAlBuffer` ? What arguments do you pass in your program when it crashes?

Answer (score 1):

`matrizAux` can only hold one character. You can't access `matrizAux[1]` - it's out of bounds.

Declare `matrizAux` like this:

```
char matrizAux[2];
```

Remember that an `n`-elements array can be indexed in positions 0 up to (and including) `n-1`.

Also, you don't need `sizeof(char)`, because it it always 1. And parentheses around `*destino` are useless in this case and make the code harder to read unnecessarily. Here's how I would change your code:

```
void concatenarAlBuffer(char **destino, char caracter) {
    char matrizAux[2];
    matrizAux[0]=caracter;
    matrizAux[1]='\0';

    *destino = realloc(*destino,2+strlen(*destino));

    if (*destino == NULL) {                               
        perror("Error al reservar memoria\n");
        exit(-1);                               
    }

    strcat(*destino, matrizAux);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You make

```
char matrizAux[1];
```

a 1-char long array.
And then you write to its' second element with

```
matrizAux[1]='\0';
```

This might or might not crash depending on what's behind your array in memory.
But it still looks like something's missing.
`realloc` can reallocate only something that was previously `malloc`- or `calloc`-ated.
Trying to reallocate something that doesn't fulfill this condition gives you your error. And that's probably the true case here.

Answer (score 0):

`char matrizAux[1]` hold only one character. Since you are accessing `matrizAux[1]`, i.e. something out-of-bounds, you are corrupting the memory. This can result in the internal data of the runtime getting corrupted, which results in the segfault during the `realloc()`, even though the realloc itself is correct.